# Hashing passwords in Node.js the same way as in Drupal 7

Tags: node.js, drupal, hash, passwords, sha512

I'm trying to migrate users from Drupal 7 to another project on node.js.

And I need to keep existing passwords for all of them. That means I need to hash passwords the same way is Drupal does.

Drupal use SHA512 by default with a salt. They run the hash through PHP's hash function numerous times to increase the computation cost of generating a password's final hash (a security technique called [stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching)).

The problem is, [user_hash_password()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21password.inc/function/user_hash_password/7.x) which does hashing, seems to be quite custom. I don't really want to revers engineer it and reinvent the wheel.

The question is, are there any libraries on node.js that can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with [drupal-hash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/drupal-hash) module.

#### Check existing password

```
var drupalHash = require('drupal-hash');

var clearPassword = 'superpassword';
var passwordHash = '$S$DODRFsy.GX2iSkl2zJ4fsrGRt2S0FOWu0JSA3BqAmSayESbcY3w9';
var isValid = drupalHash.checkPassword(clearPassword, passwordHash);
// returns true or false
```

#### Hash new password

```
var drupalHash = require('drupal-hash');

var newPassword = 'superpassword';
var passwordHash = drupalHash.hashPassword(newPassword);
// returns something like '$S$DODRFsy.GX2iSkl2zJ4fsrGRt2S0FOWu0JSA3BqAmSayESbcY3w9'
```

#### Check if an old password needs updated

```
var drupalHash = require('drupal-hash');

var passwordHash = '$P$DxTIL/YfZCdJtFYNh1Ef9ERbMBkuQ91';
var needsHash = drupalHash.needsNewHash(passwordHash);
// return true or false
```